# isUnique valitadion não funcionando cakephp 2x

Tags: cakephp, model-validation

No meu modelo, criei um valitaion pro meu campo de email, onde, se tiver um outro email ele mostra que não é possivel registrar, mas essa validação não está funcionando.

```
 public $validate = array(
    'nome' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            'message' => 'Por favor, digite seu nome'
        ),
    ),
    'email' => array(
        'mail' => array(
            'rule' => array('email', true),
            'required' => false,
            'message' => 'Not correct e-mail!'),
        'isUnique' => array(
            'rule' => 'isUnique',
            'message' => 'E-mail was registered!')),         
);
```